# MVC 3 dynamically add a viewModel to the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, editorfor

I have some viewModels similar to these:

```
public class ResturantViewModel
{
   public ResturantViewModel()
   {
       Clients.Add(new ClientViewModel());
   }
   public string MyProperty {get;set;}
   public IList<ClientViewModel> Clients = new List<ClientViewModel>();
}

public class ClientViewModel
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

In my View I have something like:

```
@foreach(var client in Model.Clients)
{
   <tr>
      <td>First Name: @Html.EditorFor(item => client.FirstName)</td>
      <td>Last  Name: @Html.EditorFor(item => client.LastName)</td>
   </tr>
}
```

I'd like to have a button which can add some new blank ClientViewModels to the ResturantViewModel.Clients list so that it could be rendered in the View and posted to the Resturant/Create action.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put your foreach in a form and bind the forms action to an action of your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). It uses the WebForms view engine but it could be very easily adapted to Razor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a list of objects inside your view

```
  <input type="text" name='Clients[@index].FirstName' value='@c.FirstName' />
  <input type="text" name='Clients[@index].LastName'  value='@c.LastName' /> 

@index++;
```

after that you have to clone these fields with next index value, so you have to got inputs like these:

```
 <input type="text" name='Clients[0].FirstName' value='@c.FirstName' />
 <input type="text" name='Clients[0].LastName'  value='@c.LastName' /> 

 <input type="text" name='Clients[1].FirstName' value='@c.FirstName' />
 <input type="text" name='Clients[1].LastName'  value='@c.LastName' /> 
 <input type="text" name='Clients[2].FirstName' value='@c.FirstName' />
 <input type="text" name='Clients[2].LastName'  value='@c.LastName' />
```

In controller you will accept a list of these objects:

```
List<Client> Clients
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank to you all here is what I've done to resolve.

first I created a new partial View _ClientRow.cshtml:

```
@using Extensions.CollectionItemsHtmlExtension
@using ClientViewModel
@model ClientViewModel
<div class = "clientEditRow">
   @using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("Clients"))
   {
      @First Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(c=>c.FirstName)
      @Last Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(c=>c.LastName)
   }
</div>
```

This partial view renders a new line for a client.
BeginCollectionItem is an Html Extension downloaded following the blog post Darin mentioned.

Then in my view I set:

```
<legend>Clients</legend>
<fieldset>
    <div id="clientEditorRows">
        @foreach(var client in Model.Clients)
        {
           Html.RenderPartial("_ClientRow", client);
        }
    </div>
    @Html.ActionLink("New Client", "NewClientRow", null, new {id = "addItem"})
</fieldset>
...
<script type="text/javascript" scr="../Scripts/listEditor.js"></script>
```

the foreach loops through all the clients and renders the partial view for every client.
Then in my Controller I wrote this method:

```
public PartialViewResult NewClientRow()
{
   return PartialView("_ClientRow", new ClientViewModel())
}
```

This method is called by the ActionLink and returns the html for a new line appending it to the previous lines.
Eventually I added this javascript file code from the blog post and modified it to my case:

```
listEditor.js

$("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) { $("#clientEditorRows").append(html); }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This js code appends the html for the new line to the page.
Hope this can help, thank you all again.

alex

P.S.: the HttpPost method receiving the values hasn't been modified and has this signature

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ResturantViewModel resturantVM)
{
   ...
}
```

to note that resturantVM.Clients receives all the values, no need to add a IList Clients parameter